# iOS 16, iPhone 11 Pro Max, app with SDK 5.2 beta 82 crashing, Library not loaded: @rpath/libjsoncpp.24.dylib

Tags: ios, linphone, ios16, jsoncpp, linphone-sdk

I compiled latest sdk 5.2 beta 82 and tried it, but app is crashing with following stack trace:

```
dyld[591]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjsoncpp.24.dylib
  Referenced from: <37C02679-31AD-371A-8BBD-1EB40F928F79> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/linphone.framework/linphone
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/BigInt.framework/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/BigInt.framework/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/local/lib/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache)
Library not loaded: @rpath/libjsoncpp.24.dylib
  Referenced from: <37C02679-31AD-371A-8BBD-1EB40F928F79> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/linphone.framework/linphone
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38841998-D49D-441F-BE5A-DFB40043F67C/personal_chat.app/Frameworks/BigInt.framework/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libjsoncpp.24.
dyld config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/usr/lib/libRPAC.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib
(lldb)
```

previously app working fine with sdk 5.2 beta 10, iOS 16 except one issue of audio has not sound

I copied latest linphone sdk 5.2 beta 82

I expected that sdk will work with my app seamlessly

Comment: did you find solution to this, I have similar issue and can not see any

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the pre-built SDK available in linphone official cocoapod repository?

Comment: i cant, i need to make some specific changes as per my server requirements for connection making logic